# Do you have any experience with Pokémon GO and slow internet?

Tags: pokemon-go

does someone has experience with playing Pokémon GO when you have used all FUP, so your connection was slowed? 
I am talking about 32kbps for downloading and 16kbps for uploading.

Answer (score 2):

All games by Niantic (Pokemon GO and Ingress) are capable of supporting very low bandwidth connections without a problem. Ingress players have been known to play through BGAN terminals, which can be slower than Dial-Up at times.

Mapping data and Pokestop Image data will take a rather decent time to load, but they will be available for the rest of your game session. As long as you do not close the game or move into a new region, you will still be able to play. Note, however, that Pokemon spawns may take a *very* long time, and catch confirmations may take just as long.

Combined with current server instability, Pokemon GO on such a slow connection will definitely be possible, but may very well be an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have a hard time downloading maps and images.

You will have to download Google Maps for your region as [offline maps](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4s71t1/suggestion_download_city_map_as_a_way_to_decrease/d57390m) in order to have a chance to play. Circling your home area won't cause much traffic, but going further away might have an impact on your game as it keeps loading data (images from PokéStops, arenas, etc).

**Edit:** As mentioned below there is a chance the offline maps no longer work, but I haven't found a reliable source, yet. This would require kinda large downloads, if you leave your home area.

Comment: I may have heard wrong but the offline map download has been debunked

Comment: I've heard about that, but I don't think they fixed it, yet. Seeing my traffic from yesterday and today it's not abnormally high like it used to be before I downloaded the maps.

Comment: The map download didn't do much for me IMO. But maybe I need to do it just for a bit longer and I might see the difference.

Comment: I guess that depends on how far you travel. For me that's 200 km every day and downloading all those maps have a good impact on your traffic. Especially with 32kb download it's a pain to download several 20-30 MB map packs. Let me know, if you see a difference after going further.

Comment: Ah that is indeed alot... I will come back to this when I have extra info!